# SVN merge with multiple revisions [Not Range]

Tags: python, svn, svn-merge

I am trying to merge some specific revisions of a source branch to destination branch. Using Python script.

When I use `svn merge --dry-run` 
range of revisions works fine. `-r 72338:HEAD`
Single revision works fine `-c 72338`.

If I use multiple revisions `-c 71750 -c 72338`, SVN merge is taking only first revision.

I need to merge multiple revisions such as  `71750`, `72338`, `72394`. 
Is it possible?

My code

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("svn merge --dry-run -c71750 -c72238 https://URL/", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, err = p.communicate()
```

Output

> Output is --- Merging r71750 into '.':
>   C    /path/to/file.java
>   Summary of conflicts:
>   Text conflicts: 1

Comment: `-c 71750 72238` is working only if the 71750 doesn't have any conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

For Multiple revisions we can use `-c` option with a space in-between the revision numbers.

`-c 71750 72238`

svn merge will go to the 72338 revision Merging only if 71750 revision doesn't have any conflicts with working copy or destination.

Comment: If you mean `svn merge -c 71750 72238 ...` that totally does not work, but `svn merge -c '71750 72238' ...` (quotes) might if 71750 does not have conflicts.